# Как устроено перенаправление потоков данных?

Tags: linux, c, bash, потоки-данных

Я пишу свой командный интерпретатор на C наподобие bash. И возник вопрос: "Как bash перенаправляет потоки?". Я искал где только мог, но кроме инструкций по применению этой возможности я ничего не нашёл.

Comment: А в исходники bash не пробовали заглянуть?

Comment: @Bulson В исходники баша лучше на заглядывать для сохранения здоровой психики.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для того, чтобы понять как работает перенаправление потоков, нужно помнить всего одну вещь: программа, запущенная с помощью `exec(2)`, наследует открытые файловые дескрипторы процесса, вызвавшего `exec(2)`.

Далее все просто. Допустим вы хотите перенаправить `stdout` какой-то утилиты в файл, например вот так:

`$ ls > output`

В вашем интерпретаторе для этого вы делаете вот так (псевдокод):

```
pid = fork()
if (!pid) { // child
  fd = open("output")
  dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO)
  exec("ls")
}
```

Для создания пайпа (`|`) используется аналогичный подход с той лишь разницей, что создается два процесса и у одного заменяет `stdin`, а у другого - `stdout`, на файловые дескрипторы, которые возвращает системный вызов `pipe(2)`.

Comment: Все сказанное верно, но вопрос был о перенаправлении, а его-то обеспечивает именно dup. Вот об этом системном вызове и расскажите ТС.

Comment: добавлю, что прежде, чем делать `dup` исходный `STDOUT_FILENO` нужно не забыть закрыть...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Нет, не нужно. `dup2(2)` делает это сам.

Comment: @PavelBorzenkov, нда, логично... был не прав — как-то просмотрел мимоходом...